# How to find the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space defined by $V:=\text{span}\{(1,1,1), (1,−1,1),(1,2,3)\}$. How do I find the dimension of $V$?

Comment: What collection of those three vectors is linearly independent (i.e. are there 1,2, or 3 linearly independent vectors there)?

Comment: Do you know the definition of "dimension" for a space?

Answer (score 2):

Row reduce the matrix with column vectors equal to these vectors. The dimension is the number of non-zero rows.